# Accessing bound method or self when decorating a method

Tags: python, python-decorators, python-descriptors

I have a use case where I want to decorate a method with an additional way to call it, such as in this code:

```
def decorator(func):
    def enhanced(*args, **kwargs):
        func(*args, **kwargs)

    func.enhanced = enhanced
    return func

@decorator
def function():
    pass

class X:
    @decorator
    def function(self):
        pass

x = X()

function()
function.enhanced()
x.function()
# x.function.enhanced()
x.function.enhanced(x)
```

The first three calls work as expected, but `x.function.enhanced()` does not; I'd have to write `x.function.enhanced(x)` to make it work. I know that this is because the `func` passed to the decorator is not a bound method but a function, and thus needs to be passed `self` explicitly.

But how can I get around this? From the little bit I understand about descriptors, they're only relevant when looking up on a class, and as `func` is not a class, `func.enhanced` is not looked up in a way that I can intercept.

Is there something I can do here?

Comment: First of all, your decorator is wrong as you're not decorating anything (you should return the `enhanced` function from within it) but that's besides the point. What exactly are you trying to achieve? As it stands, your approach doesn't make much sense - `X.function()` is a function of that class (and becomes a bound method for its instances) and as such it gets decorated long before the instance `x` even exists. Thus, it cannot know of, and consequently be bound to an instance that doesn't even exist. Furthermore, even if it could, which one of many possible instances it would be bound to?

Comment: @zwer there's nothing "wrong" with returning the original function (possibly annotated) from a decorator - it's a less common use case indeed, but just as valid as returning a wrapped function.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers - Fair point. Considering the (presumed) intention, the decorator doesn't do any _decorating_, tho.

Comment: I don't really get the "intention" here actually but that's another debate ;)

Comment: @silly-freak could you tell a bit more about the problem you're trying to solve with this "solution" ?

Comment: @zwer It does decorate. Instead of returning the decorated function directly, it makes the decorated function an attribute of the original function. Nothing wrong with this idea.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers The intention is apparently to allow the user to have a choice between calling the original function and calling the decorated version easily.

Comment: @blhsing I understood that, but I wonder about the real use case...

Comment: I'll try to outline my use case: I have background coroutines (bg) that should be run in the background of a primary coroutine (p). The bgs have a setup step, so I often want to make sure that was successful before executing p and executing the rest of bg in a task; the interface is similar to async context managers, but with execution concurrent to p instead of cleanup after p. However sometimes I want to just execute bg as a regular coroutine, just `await` it. That's the two ways of calling I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/descriptor.html) that returns an object that makes itself callable and has an `enhanced` attribute mapped to your `enhanced` wrapper function:

```
from functools import partial
def decorator(func):
    class EnhancedProperty:
        # this allows function.enhanced() to work
        def enhanced(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print('enhanced', end=' ') # this output is for the demo below only
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        # this allows function() to work
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
            class Enhanced:
                # this allows x.function() to work
                __call__ = partial(func, obj)
                # this allows x.function.enhanced() to work
                enhanced = partial(self.enhanced, obj)
            return Enhanced()
    return EnhancedProperty()
```

so that:

```
@decorator
def function():
    print('function')

class X:
    @decorator
    def function(self):
        print('method of %s' % self.__class__.__name__)

x = X()

function()
function.enhanced()
x.function()
x.function.enhanced()
```

would output:

```
function
enhanced function
method of X
enhanced method of X
```

Comment: I would just avoid putting the class definitions in the decorator function, and I would not use a nested class.

Comment: The descriptor class `EnhancedProperty` needs to be defined in the function to have access to the `func` parameter. And the `Enhanced` class has to be nested in order to gain access to the `obj` parameter of `__get__`.

Comment: They can be attributes, you don't have to use a closure. You are writing class definitions after all

Comment: Just a matter of style, really though I suppose.

Comment: That's normally true but not here. The `EnhancedProperty` class has a static method that needs access to `func`, so if I make `func` an instance variable of `EnhancedProperty` then the static method would have no access. And the `Enhanced` class needs access to the `self` parameter of the `__get__` method in order to call the static function; otherwise it would not be able to refer to the static method by class name because `EnhancedProperty` isn't yet defined then. Please try it yourself to see what I mean.

Comment: yes, but you can just use attributes for all those things. See my answer for an example

Comment: Just made `enhanced` a normal method. Retaining the nested style just so that it's different from your answer. :-)

Comment: Ah my missing link was that I can use descriptors on the original property after all. I accepted your answer as it was earlier and the nesting is more my style. @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for your take on it as well!

Answer (score 4):

Just as an example of what I mean in the comments to the answer posted by @blhsing :

```
class EnhancedProperty:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    def enhanced(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
    def __get__(self, obj, typ):
        return Enhanced(self.func, obj, typ)

class Enhanced:
    def __init__(self, func, obj, typ):
        self.func = func
        self.obj = obj
        self.typ = typ
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.func.__get__(self.obj, self.typ)(*args, **kwargs)
    def enhanced(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.func(self.obj, *args, **kwargs)

def decorator(f):
    return EnhancedProperty(f)
```

In the REPL:

```
In [2]: foo(8, -8)
Out[2]: 1040

In [3]: foo.enhanced(8, -8)
Out[3]: 1040

In [4]: Bar().baz('foo')
Out[4]: ('foo', 'foo')

In [5]: Bar().baz.enhanced('foo')
Out[5]: ('foo', 'foo')
```

Comment: Ah, the key is that I was somehow stuck on making `enhanced` a static method when there is really no need. Upvoted then. Thanks.